# Call user defined variable in another variable

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

Is it possible to call a user defined variable within another user defined variable? For example, in the screenshot below I would like to call the variable 'CmsVersion' value in 'ResultsPath'. Right now it is outputting ${CmsVersion} as the folder name and not the variable value.

[image: User Defined Variables]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables declared in the same `User defined variables` config element cannot be reused in the same element. You can move it to Test Plan level as per screenshot below
[image: Variable declared at test plan level]

In your case you will need to do another special handling because you are dealing with a windows folder path. the `\` is escape character in JAVA. When you say `\${CmsVersion}` JAVA is treating `\$` as an escape sequence.

[image]

I have declared 2 variables `CmsVersion` correlated within the same config element and `CmsVersion1` correlated from Test Plan variable.

Result is as  below in `Debug Sampler`
[image]

Comment: I like the idea of moving the variable to Test Plan level. Also, thanks for mentioning the pathing. Everything is working great, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You cannot, at least not within the bounds of a single [User Defined Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables) configuration element.

It is possible if you add **another** User Defined Variables below your original one, this way you will be able to reference the variables define in the above configuration element in the one(s) which is (are) below:

Demo:

[image]

More information: [Using User Defined Variables](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421395-Using-User-Defined-Variables-Using-User-Defined-Variables)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!